# What are expressions like «The Dutch have taken Holland» called in linguistics?

Tags: terminology, english, spanish

And does anyone by chance know any expressions of this kind in Spanish?

Some others are:

- Queen Ann is dead.
- It rains a lot in England.

Comment: What is supposed to be the common element between these? Just that they're declarative statements? Or am I failing to see something deeper?

Comment: @hippietrail - These (at least the ones about the Dutch and Queen Ann) are idioms which are used as a response to someone who says very obvious things.

Comment: Aha! I had never heard any of them in my life.

Comment: I am sure you have heard: "Is the pope catholic?"

Comment: @fdb - The obvious questions like the one about the pope are similar, but still a bit different thing. There's one such Spanish question I know of, "¿De qué color era el caballo blanco de Santiago?" (What colour was the white horse of Santiago?)

Comment: You're not asking a linguistics question, youre looking for the English word for something. I've asked similar questions to this one over on [the English Language & Usage site](http://english.stackexchange.com/). They have the poorly named tags `single-word-request` and `phrase-request`.

Comment: @YellowSky The difference is that "Is the pope catholic?" and "What colour is the white horse of Santiago?" have true answers which are arguably analytic truths, i.e. true by virtue of their meaning - a kind of tautology. The examples given initially aren't in any sense tautological - they're contingent truths where the truth of the assertion is taken for granted as being part of the common ground.

Comment: @PElliott - You're absolutely right, I agree with you, and that's what I tried to say to fdb a couple of comments before, it wasn't just so precisely formulated as you did it.

Answer (score -1):

I would call it a tautology. But this is not really a question about linguistics, but about logic.

Comment: They aren't logical tautologies - it's perfectly possible logically that Queen Anne should be alive or that the English climate should be dry.

Comment: @TKR is right - the examples you give aren't tautologies, but rather contingent truths, where the truth of the assertion is taken for granted as being part of the common ground. Interestingly though, there are cases where tautologies are used in the same role, such as, "Is the pope catholic?", which is arguably an analytic truth, i.e. true by virtue of its meaning.